# XHTML Markup Validation

Tags: xhtml, object, embed

i have my site [here][link removed]

when i run it through [validator](http://validator.w3.org/), i get several errors regarding the:

```
<embed src="inception/inception.mov" width="620" height="274" autoplay="false" controller="true" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"></embed>
```

if i keep the `<object>` and drop the `<embed>` then the code compiles fine. does this mean i no longer have to use the `<embed>` tag when im embedding multimedia in my page?

thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `<object>` instead of `<embed>` and `<param name="xxx" ...>` insteand of embed's invalid attributes.

Answer (score 1):

According to the validator output:

> Many Flash authoring tools recommend, or enforce, the usage of the <embed> element to include flash animations or applications in Web pages. <embed>, however, was never part of any standardized version of HTML, and this practice produces invalid markup.

Comment: Note that this is due to change in HTML5. (http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-iframe-element.html#the-embed-element).